# How to remove what are apparently control characters in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have some entries in notepad++ ive never seen before.  I have highlighted squares on many lines with `SGCI` `SSA` `PU1` `PU2` `MW` and `SPA` within which if copy/pasted here all translate to/become ``

I'm looking for a way to remove these from the entries.  Google indicates they are "control characters" but there are far too many for me to try and remove manually.

tried `[\x00-\x09\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F]` but apparently it did not/does not cover the offending characters.

[image]

here is an example of some lines just in case my original post wasn't clear enough.

[image]

Here is the file itself.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lymgnxy9p0atp8x/TrophyID.txt?dl=0

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the file or part of it for others to have a look? Because replacing them the way @Toto proposed should have worked.

Comment: Yes, im afraid it's due to user error somehow.  he's helped me several times and is always spot on.  I added a link to the file to the OP.

Comment: @klepp0906 Please do not link to a direct file download, instead pasting the file's contents onto [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/), then linking to it. _(Linking to a direct file download is an unnecessary security risk for any trying to help.)_

Comment: notepad++ has a menu entry for *encoding* which lets you change to UTF-8.  The answers are well-meaning but ultimately not that useful.

Comment: @JW0914 roger that!

Comment: @ThomasDickey yea i noticed that and it was already on UTF-8 by default.  Unless that was the incorrect choice.

Comment: It could have been copied from some (program) which didn't identify the encoding properly, and sent doubly-encoded data.  It's hard to say, from the limited sample. but codes in 0x80 to 0x9f range are more likely from UTF-8 than valid printable characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these characters are UTF8

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[\x{0080}-\x{0099}]` or `[\x00-\x09\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F]`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY` or whatever you want
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```ini
[                 # character class
    \x{0080}        # from character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm
  -               # upto
    \x{0099}        # character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/index.htm
]                 # end character class
```

```ini
[                 # character class
    \x00-\x09       # hex 00 to 09
    \x0B-\x0C       # hex 0B to 0C
    \x0E-\x1F       # hex 0E to 1F
]                 # end character class
```

You can adapt the range to fit exactly your needs.

**Screenshot (before):**

I've taken some lines from your example file.

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

Here I've used `XXX` as replacement to see where the replacement has been done.

[image]

Comment: this did the trick, perhaps i should have provided more information in the OP from the get-go.  Once again, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @klepp0906: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @Toto Great answer, but its layout/presentation is discombobulated.

Comment: Second example worked for me. But this did not get rid of "DEL" control characters.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that "Show All Characters" and/or "Show White Space and TAB" are enabled. Disable them by going to View -> Show Symbol, then selecting them.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: unfortunately they were not, thank you though.  I'll know to look here if I get any related funny-business in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`SGCI` or ['Single Graphic Character Introducer'](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0099) (U+0099) and `PU2`, or rather ['Private Use Two'](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0092) (U+0092) are part of the 'Latin-1-supplement' block which goes from `[\x80-\xFF]`. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) you can see all the characters in this block.

So to remove both `SGCI` and `PU2` you need to find:

```
[\x99\x92]
```

Replace by nothing.

Comment: I've extented to more characters, there are also `STS`, `CCH` and some other.

Comment: thank you for the reference.  I'll slowly pick up this gnarly regex stuff.  that reference in comparison to your expression and toto's affords me the ability to manipulate what is kept and what is omitted in the future.  filed away!  I flagged his as the answer as it evidently came in first but both work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[\x00-\x09\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F]`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[                   # character class
    \x00-\x09           # hexa 00 to 09
    \x0B-\x0C           # hexa 0B to 0C
    \x0E-\x1F           # hexa 0E to 1F
]                   # end character class
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this did not work.  0 occurrences were replaced.
unsure if relevant - but your before screenshot shows none of the highlighted strings/characters that are giving me trouble.  I assumed the regex blanket/covered them all - evidently not the case.  Please let me know if anymore information will help!  I edited my OP with a few images.

Comment: @Toto Why did you post a second answer that's the same as the first? Different regex values doesn't equal a new answer.